# Error during template rendering. Django

Tags: python, django

Я пытаюсь передать путь шаблона в DIRS, но джанго его не видит. Подскажите в чем проблема?

setting.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>
        {% block title %}
            blog Engine
        {% endblock %}
    </title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar scroll</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Link</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 offset-md-2">
            {% block content %}
                no content
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

blogengine файл urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
#from .views import hello
from django.urls import include



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
]
```

blog файл urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', posts_list)
]
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base_blog.html' %}

{% block title %}
    posts list
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="mb-5">Posts:</h1>
    {% for name in names %}
        <p>
            {{ name }}
        </p>
    {%endfor%}
{% endblock %}
```

base_blog.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в `extends` и `include` указан шаблон без пути, то он будет искаться в `templates` (если говорить упрощенно).

Вам нужно задать либо относительный путь:

```
{% extends "./base.html" %}
```

либо полный путь:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю где именно мне изменять путь. Я добавил информации. Могли бы вы уточнить?

Comment: Нужно изменить во всех местах, где делается `extend` или `include`. В конкретном случае в `base_blog.html`

Comment: На скриншоте подсвечивается красным место, где возникла ошибка. Так же рядом есть путь к файлу.